# Quantities not updating after refund on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have followed the instructions to refund products as per this link: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-refunds/

On the email sent back to the customer, the order value has been updated and takes into consideration the refund, but the order quantity does not. The quantity stays the same.

How can I make sure I am pulling the correct order quantity? When My customers come to collect their goods their receipt still shows they are to receive the original quantity?

I know order quantities are stored in the table "woocommerce_order_item_meta" with a separate "`order_item_id`" for ordered quantity and refunded quantity, the latter signalled by an additional line: `"_refunded_item_id"`. Do I need some code to sum the "`_qty`"'s?

I would like my customer emails and order reports to show the correct quantity, so happy to make just make changes to order-items.php and create a function to input into my report plugin (wp All export)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Woocommerce has no any default functionality to restore stock for cancelled and refunded orders.

There is one of the plugin to solve this solution. [Woocommerce Auto Restore Stock](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-restore-stock/) is the plugin that will help you to achieve this.

It will automatically restore your WooCommerce inventory/stock for orders that were placed and refunded or canceled.

Hope this will work for you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi There, I actually just want the quantity to show the correct quantity before I even think about restoring stock - so a customer can't come back and claim their order has not been fulfilled.

Apparently I need to use "get_qty_refunded_for_item" in the order-details-item.php file but I can't quite get it to work.

Comment: @JeffreyFong So, I found an answer to this. You need to get the Order id and the order item id when using that function. So, something like this:
`
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$item_refund_qty = $order->get_qty_refunded_for_item($order_item_id);
print_r($item_refund);
`